# Continue a while loop until EOF (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop, iterator, eof

I'm working on a program to create a list from a large QStringList. So basically after a string match, a while loop will start to add the next strings into a list. This part is working fine. The only problem I have is that the program quits unexpectedly because I don't know how I should add the EOF mechanism.

**Update with a more detailed code**

Sorry for not providing with enough details about my code. This is how my code looks now. So after the first time the string "PACKAGE TYPE" is detected, I use the function `storeLines()` function to store the next strings into one of three lists dependent. And this will continue until the next "PACKAGE TYPE" match or EOF. The only thing that is not working correctly now is when the iterator is on the last string of the QStringList. It somehow doesn't detect that the next is `inputline.end()`

```
void storeLines(QString department, QStringList::iterator current_line, QStringList::iterator endline){
while(QString::compare(*(current_line + 1),"PACKAGE TYPE") && (++current_line != endline)){ //this is not working
    if(!QString::compare(department, "MDA")) mda_list.push_back(*current_line);
    else if(!QString::compare(department, "SDA")) sda_list.push_back(*current_line);
    else mix_list.push_back(*current_line);
    }
}

void void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
   QString input = ui->listinput->toPlainText().toLatin1();
   QStringList inputline = input.split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts );

   for(QStringList::iterator pkg_header(inputline.begin()); pkg_header != inputline.end(); ++pkg_header){
       if(!QString::compare(*pkg_header,"PACKAGE TYPE")){
           ++pkg_header;
           if(!QString::compare(*pkg_header,"Department-mda:")) storeLines("MDA", pkg_header, inputline.end());
           else if(!QString::compare(*pkg_header,"Department-sda:")) storeLines("SDA", pkg_header, inputline.end());
           else storeLines("MIX", pkg_header, inputline.end());
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you know how to write the stop condition for the `for` loop, but not for the `while` loop? You should use the same check in both places, of course.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have simplified the code. In reality the `while` loop is done in another function. I tried to add `inputline.end()` as parameter, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, you'd have to make it work. Comparing to end iterator *is* how you detect end of range. Your attempts to compare to `NULL` are nonsense.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `The program has unexpectedly finished.` Can it be that it is not possible to add `inputline.end()` as a parameter for the `storeLines()` function?

Comment: No, it likely means you have a logical bug in your program. Off the top, `*(current_line + 1)` is invalid if `current_line` is already equal to `end()`, or points to the last element right before `end()`.

Comment: Why do you use `QString::compare`? Use `operator==`, make the code easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apparent intent is to find the string "PACKAGE TYPE" in the existing list, and then copy the remaining elements in the list to a new list.

If that's the case, then why not do exactly that?

```
for(QStringList::iterator current_line(inputline.begin()); current_line != inputline.end(); ++current_line){
    if(!QString::compare(*current_line,"PACKAGE TYPE"){
        list.insert(list.end(), ++current_line, inputline.end());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about the problem. I've updated the code with a more detailed description. The thing is that I need to keep track of the EOF and an eventual next "PACKAGE TYPE" match.

Comment: There's no such thing called "EOF". "EOF" means "end of file", when reading its contents. There are no files here. You still cannot explain cogently what you want.

Comment: Okay, so I want to figure out how I can check if `current_line` is on the last string of the QStringList. I have a QStringList, where there are several sections, each section starting with the string "PACKAGE TYPE". The next string defines which department the package belongs to; it can be in mda, sda or in mix department. And then I want to store the following strings into the department lists until the next "PACKAGE TYPE" section or the end of QStringList.

Comment: Have a simple loop that iterates over the entire list, and nothing more. Inside the loop, whenever "PACKAGE TYPE" is encountered, the package type is saved in a separate variable. Otherwise, look at the previously-saved "PACKAGE TYPE" variable, to see what was seen, previously, and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a parser - it's often simplest to write it like you'd usually write one, by making the states explicit and iterating in sequence over every element of the input stream. You won't make any off-by-one iterator errors that way.

This code matches the intent in your question, and makes it obvious that you've missed a case: when you expect a department, you don't react to the `PACKAGE TYPE` being present. You could signal an error, or stay in the `DEPARTMENT` state, but I presume you should handle it and not just ignore it.

```
QStringList mda_list, sda_list, mix_list;

void parse(const QString & input) {
    enum {
        TYPE,
        DEPARTMENT,
        ITEMS
    } state = TYPE;
    auto list = &mix_list;
    auto const kPackageType = QStringLiteral("PACKAGE TYPE");

    for (auto const element : input.split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts)) {
        switch (state) {
        case TYPE:
            if (element == kPackageType)
                state = DEPARTMENT;
            break;
        case DEPARTMENT:
            if (element == QStringLiteral("Department-mda:"))
                list = &mda_list;
            else if (element == QStringLiteral("Department-sda:"))
                list = &sda_list;
            state = ITEMS;
            break;
        case ITEMS:
            if (element == kPackageType)
                state = DEPARTMENT;
            else
                *list << element;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The use of `QStringLiteral` gives you compile-time-built string instances to compare against. The code would work about just as well if you removed the `QStringLiteral(...)` wrappers, at a cost due to inevitable premature pessimization though.